# About Android Mobile Application Realtime Architecture?

Tags: android, sockets, android-activity, socket.io

In terms of Android mobile development's extends Application, would it be possible to create a Websocket listener (Socket.IO, etc) in the application for notification, while also creating a flag in the extends Application class, while ALSO having the class or fragment of some sorts that displays the actual data to have a while loop of the flag from the extends Application class to lets say refresh the data display?  Or is extends Application static in a way and the live time updates cannot work?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, yes. Yes it is possible to utilise the `Application` class to listen for external events. `Application` instance lives alongside your app. So in theory it is feasible to use it as a somewhat listener and then dispatch the events to the currently resumed `Activity`/`Fragment`.

That said, I don't think deriving `Application` just to act as a listener would deemed as a good practice. Android has provided the [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) class which was built for these use-cases in mind. Put simply, they act just like Activity but without any UI whatsoever.

It is where I think would be the best place to listen for events. You could then command the aforementioned Service to fire off a Broadcast whenever an event of interest is being detected. After all of that, what is left is to assign a [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) in your `Activity`/`Fragment` and update its state according to the event you've just received.